# Python Function that returns greatest integer

Tags: python, function, input, integer

Hi I am trying to create a python function that when I enter in 3 integers, and it has to be 3!, it will return the greatest integer I put in.

so like if I input (3, 4, 5)
it will return to me "5"

can someone plz help me ASAP?!?

I want it to be a FUNCTION... so it needs to be reusable...

I want it to start like "def name (x, y, z):

Comment: He could at least have shown some code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is [`max()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function.

So, having that, you'll have the following program:

```
def input_max3():
    return max(int(input()) for i in range(3))
```

Here `input()` reads a string from the user and `int(...)` converts it to integer value. To have 3 values we have an generator expression `(... for i in range(3))` and `max(...)` takes maximum out of the values generated.

Or, if you don't need any command-line input from the user, you might just use it as it is: `max(1, 3, 5)`.

Comment: yes but how do I form the function as a whole? can you please write out the function for me? sorry, i am new to python

Comment: sorry I am still a bit confused

Comment: @StevenLi I've added a usage example for your case.

Comment: i need it in function format, so like... def(watever)..

Comment: @StevenLi OK, here you have it :)

Comment: def input_max3():
    return max(int(input()) for i in range(3))

print input_max3:(1, 2, 3)

Comment: how do I bring out the function? to test it out?

Comment: @StevenLi If I understand correctly what you need, just call it like this: `print(max(1, 2, 3))`. But, if you need an interactive function, then you should put `def input_max3(): return max(int(input()) for i in range(3))` first, then, call it with `input_max3()` and input 1, 2 and 3 line by line. Start with the first one, please.

Comment: Do any of you guys know the raw code for the function max()? my tutor wants me to make a function where I input only THREE integers, and have the function return the greatest of the three. When I contacted him for help, he told me to make it like "def funcname (x, y, z): " Can you guys help me make a function with the x, y, and z?

Answer (score 1):

```
def input(*args):
    return max(args)
print input(1,2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

list= [[456, 700, 200]

print "Max value element : ", max(list);

## output : Max value element :  700